# Is there a way to get all the NEWS.gz which is/was this year in /usr/share/doc/ of $PACKAGENAME

Tags: debian, sed, awk, grep, regular-expression

If people go into `/usr/share/doc/$PACKAGENAME` (you can use any valid package name which you have installed on your system) you will see that the directory has various files in it, at the very least `changelog.Debian.gz`, `changelog.gz`, copyright and sometimes `README.Debian`, `TODO.Debian` and `NEWS.gz`. Now what I would like to have is a listing of all the `NEWS.gz` which has been changed this year, i.e. the time-stamps are of this year only. Is such a way possible ?

The only way I see this being done is using some sort of regexp, any takers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

relaying on date might be tricky, however, what about

```
cd /usr/share/doc

## less that 365 dyas
find . -mtime -365 -type f -name NEWS.gz

## since 1-1-2015
touch -t 201501010000 /tmp/ref
find . -newer /tmp/ref -type f -name NEWS.gz
```

you can give a 'touch' of complexity

```
touch -t $(date +%Y)01010000 /tmp/ref
```

Comment: Thank you, I should have thought of find myself, I was just setting it for myself, wasn't I ? Making it more complex when the answer was straight-forward. Look forward to answers from more people as well.